# How to POSIX-ly find out how many CPU threads do I have within a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, grep, scripting, cpu, posix

How to POSIX-ly find out how many CPU threads do I have within a shell script?

I know I can somehow use `/proc/cpuinfo`, but how to get only the count of repeating lines, maybe using `grep`?

Comment: POSIX does not really care about CPUs or how to get information about these. Write something specifically aimed at your (type of) operating system, e.g. Linux, instead. Getting the CPU count on a BSD system will be totally different anyway. Most Unixes has a different layout of their `/proc` filesystem, if it exists at all.

Comment: Well, Solaris has the procfs 2  filesystem written by Roger Faulkner who introduced procfs into UNIX. So /proc on Solaris is from the procfs origins...The CPU info is unrelated to procfs. This is an implementation mistake from Linux.

Comment: Currently, the is no POSIXly correct way to find out the number of CPU threads within a shell script.

Comment: Older Stack Overflow question: [How to obtain the number of CPUs/cores in Linux from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6481005) - one answer mentions Linux coreutils `nproc`; various others propose ways to process `/proc/cpuinfo`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`getconf`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getconf.html) might be the most portable, see for example [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/jj1bdx/5746298):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Linux and similar...
CPUS=$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN 2> /dev/null) ||
# FreeBSD (and derivatives), OpenBSD, MacOS and similar...
CPUS=$(getconf NPROCESSORS_ONLN 2> /dev/null) ||
# Solaris and similar...
CPUS=$(ksh93 -c 'getconf NPROCESSORS_ONLN' 2> /dev/null) ||
# Give up...
CPUS=1
```

Comment: The problem with `_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN` is that this is a Solaris extension from 1992 that is not yet in POSIX. It is not even in the Solaris `getconf` program and only David Korn added it to the internal builtin version from ksh93. I guess you need a ksh93 from 2008 or later (the ksh93 integration into OpenSolaris).

Comment: Why do you use backticks? I'm going to replace them now, feel free to correct it if meaningful.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak The syntax you use does not work on various UNIX systems since POSIX does not grant a POSIX shell to be under `/bin/sh`.